# Strange bash message when source-ing file

Tags: bash, macos, bsd, bash4

```
ql_get_latest(){
  . "$BASH_SOURCE";
}
export -f ql_get_latest;
```

when I run `bash`, I drop into a shell:

and then when I run `ql_get_latest` I get:

> ```
> bash: environment: No such file or directory
> ```

anybody know what that's about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BASH_SOURCE` (or specifically, the element at index 0 of that array) is the name of the file where a function definition occurs. Since your shell inherits `ql_get_latest` from its parent, the name of the "source file" is set to `environment`. You can see this (and another special case) if you simply echo the value of the variable from the function.

```
$ foo () { echo "$BASH_SOURCE"; }
$ foo
main
$ export -f foo
$ bash
$ foo
environment
```

In your case, you are attempting to source the file named `environment`, which doesn't exist. (And if it did, it wouldn't necessarily be related to `ql_get_latest` in any way.)